# How do I make an applcation's launch icon run the preferences activity?

Tags: java, android

I would like an app's launch icon run the app's preferences activity (as it has no Activities, only a Service).

The preferences are defined in res/xml/preferences.xml.

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: It has "no Activited" but you want to launch the "preferences activity"? Something must be wrong here, why not create a "preferences activity" and launch it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create an activity for your preference (PreferenceActivity), add that activity in your manifest and provide appropriate intent-filters as shown below to run through launcher:

```
<activity android:name=".MyPreferenceActivity" android:label="Preferences" android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Chris, you need a Java class called PreferenceActivity that extends Activity to launch it. If using Eclipse this should be generated for you when you make a new project.